# AXIS2 not generating all classes for WSDL file

Tags: web-services, jboss, apache-axis, axis, wsdl2java

I am new to webservices. I am trying to change the my application webservices from JBOSS(Currently using)  to AXIS2. Using JBOSS everything is worked fine but the same WSDL when i gave as input to AXIS2 wsdl2java.bat, it is not creating all the classes and stubs which leads to compile error as the compiler missed many files. Could you please any one tell me that, what could be the reason and solution for the case. My build script mentioned below. I have been doing my R&D since 1 week and didnt find any clue. Hope your answers will lead me to further steps...

```
  <target name="make-server-template">
   <!-- Using AXIS2 -->
    <echo>Generating and compiling ${service_name}. ${server.def.package}..</echo>
    <exec dir="." executable="${wsconsume}">
    <arg line=" -o ${server.srcautogen.dir}
        -p ${package.name}
        -uri ${wsdl.dir}/${wsdl.file}"/>
   </exec>

   <!-- commented.... Using JBOSS ..Everything is perfect
    <exec dir="." executable="${wsconsume}" error="${wsc.logfile}">
     <arg line="-s ${server.srcautogen.dir} -o ${serverbuild.dir} -k 
                -e -p ${package_name} ${wsdl.dir}/${wsdl.file}"/>
    </exec> -->
   </target>
   <target name="make-server-artifacts" depends="clean,prepare">

   <antcall target="make-server-template">
     <param name="service_name" value="WSDLFILE"/>
     <param name="package.name" value="${server.def.package}"/>
   </antcall>
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that all missing files are related to axis2.

When you generated java files for your web services using axis2, it generates Java classes that related to the WSDL file only. But it refers most of axis2 classes in order to make the communication work with web service.

Therefore, if you want to use those files in your code, you have to include most of axis2 libraries in your project's classpath.

As the first step, include all jar files you can find in axis2/lib folder into your project. It will work.